# How do I recover from a broken gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've recently started working on my first Sinatra/CouchDB app and kept running into a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` error. After a ton of googling, I've discovered that one of the gems I've been using, json-1.4.3, is apparently broken :/

I uninstalled the gem, and installed json-1.4.2 instead, but I'm still getting the error. I'm wondering if I need to do something to make sure that 1.4.2 is being used now instead of the broken 1.4.3?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Rather than editing the title of a question to mark it `[solved]`, here on Stack Overflow, we accept answers.  Just go ahead and click the green check mark next to chenge's answer!  People will be able to tell that your question is solved because the "preview" will show up with yellow text on green instead of white on green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can list the gems to see if you have two gems.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't think it would be that simple - I thought I might have to refresh a cache somewhere or something like that. Thanks!